# Not able to install: gem install cocoapods in Macbook Terminal

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Not working below commands on MacBook Terminal:

gem install cocoapods,
gem install cocoapods-art

Getting bellow error message:

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository

I have tried many solutions which are available on Google/Stackoverflow but not worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `which ruby` output, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have satisfied other conditions and you wish to install the latest version of cocoapods, you may wish to install using homebrew.

To do that, you can install with this command on your terminal;

```
brew install cocoapods
```

You will be required to link cocoapods after installing - to link, use;

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Hope it works for you...